# Simple way of seperating large number into 2 numbers? c++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to make a program that separates a large number like 123456 into 1234 and 56.
The problem that I find is that I don't know how many numbers there will be, all I need is the last 2 digits and the first half.

So basically I can get 12345678 and I need 1. 12345 2. 78

Maybe someone got an idea how should I try to do it? Feeling kind of lost and have no idea how should I start this..

Comment: `i % 100` for last two digits. Subtract from original (and divide by 100) to get the other part.

Comment: `int x = 12345678; int x1 = x / 100; int x2 = x - x1 * 100;`

Comment: That worked really well. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int x = 12345678; int x1 = x / 100; int x2 = x - x1 * 100;
```

or

```
int x2 = i % 100;
```